# Vaadin slow in Internet Explorer

Tags: performance, internet-explorer, memory-leaks, vaadin

We have a huge application in Vaadin 6.8.15. It runs fast in chrome, firefox and Safari.
But in ie it is getting slower and slower with every click. We have views with tabs which
have up to ten tabbars and up to 50 controls. Also the memory of ie is growing and growing and never freed.

Any ideas ?

Thank you.

Comment: Vaadin is based on javascript. IE8 and lower versions have the slowest javascript engine on the market, and that by magnitudes (http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/windows-xp-web-browser-performance,3167-7.html) IE9 and IE10 are much faster, but compared to current chrome and ff releases still slower in many use cases. Your only chance is to reduce the number of components in the DOM tree (Remove HorizontalLayout etc.)

Comment: You are running Vaadin in production mode? Take a look here: https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/4182249

Comment: If possible, you also could try to update your Vaadin version (of course, this will not be an automatic and zero-effort update)

Comment: It is on IE 9,10, or 11.
The problem occurs when we use tabsheets with a lot of compoments.

We cannot move to vaadin 7, because that would be a 6-8 month task.
So our workaround is to "simulate the tabsheets with panels and buttons.

Comment: I have encountered the same problem in Firefox 38 (most recent version). The app starts normally but after a while is getting slower and slower. Apart from using Chrome, I don't think there is a solution, especially in IE which is generally slower.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes because you are using so many listeners in your components, and communication tends to collapse, so, try to handle the listeners in a way you don't and them to many components.

In the other hand, as far as I tested vaadin, not removing the components after they are not used, causes the DOM to crash. I mean, if you don't need a component, why to show it?, it will consume a lot of memory.